# Import Error on server, but working OK in local machine

Tags: python, django, python-3.3, importerror, openshift

I have the following project structure:

```
apps(python package)
      |
      |
      |----------trips(python package)
                   |----__init__.py
                   |----urls.py
                   |----views.py
    project
    manage.py
```

urls.py file has the following imports:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from . import views
```

The app works perfectly fine when running on a local machine (I've made lots of apps like this, so I don't think the mistake is that obvious, but who knows)
When I upload this to a production server (Openshift with python 3), I see Django's debug template, stating an ImportError ocurred:

```
ImportError at /

cannot import name views
```

The line of the Exception is:

```
from . import views
```

I've tried also:

```
from apps.trips import views
```

with no luck...
Any ideas?

Update:
This is my Python path:

Python Path:

```
['/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/app-root/runtime/repo',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py3.3.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/app-root/runtime/repo',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/psycopg2-2.5.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6-py3.3.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django_selectable-0.7.0-py3.3.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django_autocomplete_light-2.0.0a4-py3.3.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/six-1.4.1-py3.3.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/South-0.8.4-py3.3.egg',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/opt/lib/python33.zip',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/opt/lib/python3.3',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/opt/lib/python3.3/plat-linux',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/opt/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py3.3.egg-info',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/opt/lib/python3.3/site-packages',
 '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/hector_transporte']
```

The last line points to my project folder (the one that contains the apps module). Another strange thing is django seems to be able to find my settings.py

I'm using the python 3 cartridge because "it's the present and future of the language"

Comment: are you running the application with apache (or a like) or django's own developement server?

Comment: Locally Ive tried both Apache and Django's server. OpenShift uses uwsgi I think.. Can it be related to that? django is getting the request, that's for sure

Comment: my guess is that you need to struct your project to the correct paths that are searched by open shift. put a `print syt.path``statement before your failing import and see what is searched for

Comment: I've tried what you said, but it's still not finding it.. I'm updating the question with my python path, to see if it helps

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the python 3 cartridge at this time? We have a new one coming out in about 3 weeks that will be more standard. We even have a quickstart for django with the 2.7 cart - https://github.com/openshift/django-example

Comment: I started out with python 3 and chose open shift because they have it :) I'll try a while longer before going back in time to 2.7 (A bit lazy about changing my code to be compatible with 2.7 also)... I'll wait for the next cartridge!

Comment: The quickstart says it's for python 2.6... is that wrong?

Comment: Can you login to the machine a directly import the views.py? An ImportError can also indicate, that something is wrong inside the module...

Comment: Man you saved my life! I was missing a dependency for one of the packages I imported. Thanks!!! Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImportError can arise when there is a problem with the module you are importing. In this case, one of the dependences for the views module was missing on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to use the python 3 cartridge at this time? We have a new one coming out in about 3 weeks that will be more standard. We even have a quickstart for django with the 2.7 cart - github.com/openshift/django-example

Comment: +1 for the new cartridge! But the problem was a missing dependency for the project

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reference to {python_home}/Lib/site-packages/django.  You might try adding that to your path.

Comment: It's right there: '/var/lib/openshift/52a6379ae0b8cd1b10000001/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6-py3.3.egg',